# including php document from root

Tags: php

I have PHP pages in diffrent directorys in my root eg.

```
http://mydomain.com/forum/?action=thread&threadid=9284
http://mydomain.com/library/?s=achievements
```

I need to include a file on every php document which is in root dir.

```
include('header.php');
```

does not work

On for example `/root/forum/index.php` i want to include header.php that is in /root/header.php

which is in /root/

My english is not best but I hope you understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple ways to do this:

- You can add your header into php default include path:
  set_include_path("/path/to/includes");
  You can make this change permanent by changing your php.ini file.
- You can create a variable/define which is the common default root folder:

  $path=dirname(`__FILE__`);
  include($path."header.php");

Answer (score 0):

You could use `include '../header.php'`.